# Async line of code is like its invinsible

Tags: discord.js

I dont know much of javaScript and i wanted to make a bot from a youtube tutorial. Now the video said to type this:

```json
    (async () => {
                try {
                    if (process.env.ENV === "production") {
                    await rest.put(Routes.applicationCommands(CLIENT_ID), {
                        body: commands
                    });
                    console.log("Globally");
                 } else {
                    if (process.env.ENV === "production") {
                        await rest.put(Routes.applicationGuildCommands(CLIENT_ID, process.env.GUILD_ID)
                        , {
                            body: commands
                        });
                        console.log("Locally");
                 }
            } 
    
        } catch (err) {
            if (err) console.error(err);
        }
        })
```

Inside the **client.once("ready",**

So it turned out something like this:

```json
client.once("ready", () => {
    console.log("Bot is online.");

    const CLIENT_ID = client.user.id;

    const rest = new REST({
        version: "9"

    }).setToken(process.env.TOKEN);

    (async () => {
            try {
                if (process.env.ENV === "production") {
                await rest.put(Routes.applicationCommands(CLIENT_ID), {
                    body: commands
                });
                console.log("Globally");
             } else {
                if (process.env.ENV === "production") {
                    await rest.put(Routes.applicationGuildCommands(CLIENT_ID, process.env.GUILD_ID)
                    , {
                        body: commands
                    });
                    console.log("Locally");
             }
        } 

    } catch (err) {
        if (err) console.error(err);
    }
    }) 
});
```

Now as you can see it says that if it finds client id it should type on console "Locally" to see if it works. But the terminal is like it ignores the whole async it just says that the bot is online nothing for the commands. What did i do wrong

Comment: You never call the async function... You only declare it

Comment: @vicatcu how could i call it a function? Edit: Nvm but if i call it a function 4 problems pop up
Edit: I found out that if i remove the "=>" it removes all errors
Edit again: When i remove it the terminal crashes

Comment: Edit again again: It specifically says: **app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...** Btw im running it with npm run dev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of defining a separate asynchronous function inside the ready handler function, why not just make the ready handler function itself asynchronous? Here's an example:

```js
client.once("ready", async () => {
    console.log("Bot is online.");

    const CLIENT_ID = client.user.id;

    const rest = new REST({
        version: "9"

    }).setToken(process.env.TOKEN);

    try {
        if (process.env.ENV === "production") {
            await rest.put(Routes.applicationCommands(CLIENT_ID), {
                body: commands
            });
            console.log("Globally");
        } else {
                await rest.put(Routes.applicationGuildCommands(CLIENT_ID, process.env.GUILD_ID)
                    , {
                        body: commands
                    });
                console.log("Locally");
             
        } 

    } catch (err) {
        if (err) console.error(err);
    }
});
```

That should allow the async function to run.

### EDIT

Your `if` statements were slightly incorrect. You are checking if `process.env.ENV` equals production, and `else`, you are once again checking if it equals production. I've fixed that in this answer.

Comment: No it doesnt work it says: **await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules** and because i didnt put the async it cant be executed

Comment: Did you copy this code exactly? The `await` is in an async function. Look at the `client.once` line.

Comment: yea i didnt see that sorry. The exact same thing happened. The terminal says "the bot is online" but not "locally" which would mean that the commands work locally. So its the same if i didnt do it at all

Comment: Do you want it to run locally when `process.env.ENV` is not equal to `production`? If so, your `if` statements are set up wrong. I can edit the answer to fix that.

Comment: Try it now. I've edited the answer. Didn't see that issue initially.

Comment: I just want it for the commands to work locally (i did put client_id on .env file) and it just does not want to work idk. If you think that would work i can give it a chance i have nothing to lose. Thanks!
Trying it rn

Comment: OMG YOU ARE A GOD HOW DID YOU FIX IT?

Comment: AAnd if i wanted to change it to global what should i change?

Comment: If you want to change it to global, you need to change process.env.ENV to equal "production". Either in your env variables, or by doing `process.env.ENV = "production"` somewhere at the top of your file.

Comment: As for what the issue was, your `if` statement was checking if ENV equals production. If so, it would do global commands. If not, it would go into the `else` statement. Note, it only goes into the `else` statement if ENV is not equal to production. But in your `else`, you had another `if` statement checking if ENV is equal to production. Since the `else` is only reached if ENV *isn't* equal to production, that `if` statement prevented your code from even getting to the local command code.

Comment: Dude i dont know how to thank you. Just Thank you so much ive been trying to fix this for a long time and you fixed it for me.. Thank you

Comment: i know that you might cant rn but i tried to put it on its own .js file and run it from there and im kinda stuck again. I dont know where to put the async 
```json
module.exports = {
    name: "ready", 
    once: true,
    execute(client, commands) {
        console.log("Bot is online.");

    const CLIENT_ID = client.user.id;

    const rest = new REST({
        version: "9"

    }).setToken(process.env.TOKEN);

    try {
        if (process.env.ENV === "production") 
```
and you know the rest

Comment: You always put the `async ` before the function that contains the `await` keyword. In this case, that function is `execute()`. So put `async` before `execute()`.

Comment: Thanks! I am so sorry but can you seem to help me on my new question? Another guy posted an answer but it wasnt what i was looking for. Sorry and thank you